# Android SQLite timestamp alteration

Tags: android, sqlite, timestamp

I'm saving the timestamp of a user action to a SQLite Database. It all works fine except the time stamp is in GMT. I need to change it to +x hours ahead, but I'm having trouble formatting the SQL command:

```
myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+ DATE_TABLE+" VALUES(null,'"+spt.toString()+"',datetime())" );
```

datetime() function gives the GMT time/date stamp. AS shown here http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

I tried datetime('localtime') which gives a value of NULL.
I tried datetime('+x hour') with hour and hours which returned NULL.

I want to know how to alter the time stamp for localtime?

Comment: Can you show us the table description and the type of "spt"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these:

datetime('now','localtime')

datetime('now','+4 hours')